# Dynamic Permissions in Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I was wondering if it's possible for third-party apps to dynamically add permission to the system or not. According to [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=y11NBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=%22applications%20can%20also%20add%20new%20permissions%20dynamically%20using%20the%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.addPermission()%22&source=bl&ots=nU_ACVpR2x&sig=ZXYNDYBcFgqwi9uCVfUvUzN58ZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTo_OH9-DRAhWQ0YMKHXv8CKoQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22applications%20can%20also%20add%20new%20permissions%20dynamically%20using%20the%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.addPermission()%22&f=false), it is possible through the use of the public addPermission() API; however, I am getting a SecurityException that says "java.lang.SecurityException: You either need MANAGE_USERS or CREATE_USERS permission to: query users". I just wanted to make sure it is really because the system doesn't allow it and not because I messed up something in my code. If it is the case, dynamic addition of permissions is not allowed to third-party apps not signed with the system certificate, it would be great if somebody could explain the reasoning behind this choice.

Here is how I add the permission programmatically:

```
public void addDynamicPermission() {
    PermissionInfo pi = new PermissionInfo();
    pi.name = "com.somedomain.permission.MY_PERMISSION";
    pi.labelRes = R.string.permission_label;
    pi.protectionLevel = PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS;
    final PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    packageManager.addPermission(pi);
}
```

This is what I have in my manifest file:
`<permission-tree android:name="com.somedomain.permission" />`

and this is the full java stack for the exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 11824
java.lang.SecurityException: You either need MANAGE_USERS or CREATE_USERS permission to: query users
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.addPermission(IPackageManager.java:2870)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.addPermission(ApplicationPackageManager.java:535)
at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.addDynamicPermission(MainActivity.java:183)
at com.example.myapp.MainActivity$6.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#addPermission(android.content.pm.PermissionInfo)

Comment: I recommend that you provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are attempting to do this, showing the `<permission-tree>`, the `addPermission()` call, and the full Java stack trace associated with your crash. Generally, apps add custom permissions via `<permission>` elements in the manifest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: The book is outdated and versions of Android newer than Lollipop do indeed require `MANAGE_USERS` or `CREATE_USERS`, both of which have a *protectionLevel* of 3 (*signatureOrSystem*).

Longer answer:

A while back, in the KitKat era, I wrote some test code similar to yours and I recall it working fine.  That was a few years ago.  I just fired up that old app in my current Nougat (7.0) environment and ended up with the exact same exception that you are seeing.  Curious, I reinstalled KitKat (4.4.4), Lollipop (5.1), and Marshmallow (6.0) instances and tried the app on each.

For 4.4.4 and 5.1, everything works fine. I verified this by running the code and then checking for the existence of the custom permission as follows:

```
% adb shell dumpsys package packagename | grep -i com.example
...
Permission [com.example.permission.TEST_PERMISSION] (79c4d6d):
sourcePackage=com.example.myapplication
perm=Permission{2c725da2 com.example.permission.TEST_PERMISSION}
...
```

However, on 6.0 and 7.0, I'm getting the security exception. A quick check of [androidxref.com](http://androidxref.com) indicates that the exception is coming from either the `getPrimaryUser` or `getUsers` method in `UserManagerService`.

`getPrimaryUsers` doesn't exist in 4.4.4 or 5.1, and `getUsers` has always been protected with `checkManageOrCreateUsersPermission`. Therefore, I think its reasonable to assume that the `addPermission` chain was modified starting in 6.0 to get a list of users for some reason.  So `addPermission` does not require `MANAGE_USERS` or `CREATE_USERS`, but a method it now calls does.

Whether or not this additional access control check is intended and the reasoning behind why, are questions I cannot answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul for this very detailed answer!

Comment: On Android 5 or before, how do I get a permission granted to the app that dynamically created it? I tried using <uses-permission> tag in the manifest file as well as updating the app after the permission is created, but they simply didn't work.